# 1024 overriding a function that is not marked for override

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action, flash-cs5

I keep getting this error in a Flash instrument I'm making:

> 1024 overriding a function that is not marked for override

The error was found in this line:

```
public function stop():void
```

Comment: dynamic, const, final, override, implement, extends, public, internal, protected, private, custom_nameSpace, void, use... what else am i missing??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error indicates that you have a method named `stop` in base class. So in derived class you need to add `override` in the method declaration.

```
public override function stop():void
       ^
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the function name **stop** in a class that extends MovieClip.

Comment: You can i accidently had the linkage name the same as the movie clip name which was causing the error

Comment: stop is a reserved method on MovieClip, used for stopping the timeline animation. If your class extends MovieClip you won't be able to use this method name without overriding it:  public override function stop():void